# Get rows based on maximum value for subsets of a table

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to filter a table based on the values of one column, then get the maximum value for each of these values.

e.g.

```
id | value
-----------
0  | 10
0  | 22
0  | 50
1  | 33
1  | 4
2  | 5
2  | 23
2  | 33
3  | 22
3  | 50
```

Filter by rows with IDs 2 and 3, then get the maximum of each id

```
id | value
-----------
2  | 33
3  | 50
```

How do I use that using hibernate?

This is my attempt:

```
    List<int> ids = ... // Retreived from elsewhere

    Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();
    for(int id: ids){
        disjunction.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));    // Specify which IDs
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Item> items= (List<Item>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createCriteria(Item.class)
            .add(disjunction)
            .setProjection(
                Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.max("value"))
                    .add(Projections.groupProperty("id")
                )
            )
            .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
            .list();
```

This is just giving me the 'id' with the highest value (e.g. 3, not the entire row)

I am trying to do this in a spring mvc app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a `WHERE` clause in your `CriteriaQuery`, and then do a multiselect to do the `GROUP BY`:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> query = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);
Root<Item> item = query.from(Item.class);
query.where(cb.equal(item.get("id"), 2));
query.where(cb.equal(item.get("id"), 3));
query.multiselect(item.get("id"), item.max("value")).groupBy(item.get("id"));

List<Object[]> results = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
System.out.println("id | value\n-----------");
for(Object[] object : results){
    System.out.println(object[0] + " | " + object[1]);
}
```

Comment: Any way to do this using hibernate's criteria rather than the jpa criteria builder?

Answer (score -1):

```
select MAX(id),max(value) from ABCD where id in (110,56001) group by id
```

Try this Query to execute in the form to get the expected output.